# Google Charts Column width in pixels

Tags: google-visualization

I have set the width of my bar chart to 580px. The problem that the chart overflows the area in the view window. Would it be possible to reduce the size of the columns in the chart area to reduce the overall chart size? I mean would it be possible to change the scale for the numbers per pixel for each column so that for example the 280 number is shown in less pixel space?

[image: Google Chart]

Comment: You want to look at the "chartArea" part of the options. I'd be happy to finish an answer if you post your code.

Comment: Pinging again. If you insert your code, I'd be happy to help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use responsive BarChart.

```
var options = {
  width: "100%", //adjusts according to the screen size 
  height: 500,
  bar: { groupWidth: "75%" },
  legend: { position: 'right', textStyle: { color: 'black' } },
  isStacked: true,
  vAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'black' } },
  hAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'black' }, format: ' #,##0.00' },
  chartArea: { width: "50%", height: "70%" }};

function resizeCharts() {
   // redraw charts, dashboards, etc here
   chart.draw(dadosGrafico, options);}
```

`$(window).resize(resizeCharts);`